# How to get the number of lines of the message label used before the uitableview cell is being display

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a label in the cell, now i am customize my cell and added a label into the cell. I am creating a chatting apps, however on the top of the conversation , i need to determine the top constraint suppose to given to the profile image or the message label, if the message label only got one line , the top constraint is given to the profile image, if the message label is taller than the profile image, i will give the constraint to the message label. Ok the logic sound good, but the problem is come, i added the above logic under the initialiser as below

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
print(messageLabel.frame.height)

}
```

However, when the cell is being created, the print result gave to me is 0, in the end i suspect the message label is havent created so the height is 0.

In this case, i use the following function

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if messageLabel.frame.height != 0
    {
        if self.messageLabel.tag != 1
        {
            messageLabel.tag = 1
            if (bubbleImageView.frame.height > 60)
            {
                contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 4.5))
            } else
            {
                contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 4.5))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it is work, the message label returned me the value of the height, but there is a bug on the above code which is, the cell is display first, the code only can be execute , in this case , when i debug it in the simulator, it took one second before execute the code, in this case, the user will see how the cell transform from none constraint to have constraint which is a bad practice for the user experience. In the end, i have to return back how to get the number of lines of the message label before the cell being displayed. So i can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this in `func layoutSubviews()` since your code now will add the constraint several times (`func layoutSubviews()` is executed more than once). The issue you are having is pretty much what your conclusion is, the label hasn't been laid out yet since this will happen when `layoutSubviews()` is executed. What you can do however is to force the `layoutSubviews()` to run before you add your constraint.

I don't really understand which views needs to be forced though, but in `viewDidLoad` for your `UITableViewController` you do

```
view.setNeedsLayout()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and in your init for your cell you do the same for `self`. Maybe even for the `label` itself.

Comment: thanks for your code for the view.layoutifneeded(), it helped me to get some value although it is not the value i want. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This function will return the number of line tableview will show

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myArray.count
}
```

It is `numberOfRowsInSection` from tableView delegate function

Comment: sorry what i want is the message label number of lines used or the height of the message label